# Is there any way to transfer system properties to sub-processes?

Tags: java

I'm writing a program that forms a new sub-process in a following pattern:

```
proc = java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar Xxx.jar");
```

Though the environment variables are automatically inherited to sub-processes, I think the system properties defined by `-D<name of property>=<value of the property>` are not.

My question is, if there is any way to transfer the system properties programmatically. Any comments or answers are welcomed. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution that I've come up with is to define a set of properties to pass to subprocesses, and create a `-D<key>=<value>` strings from it.

```
static String[] properties_to_pass = {
    "log4j.configuration"
};
```

Above is the set of system properties to pass. Then...

```
StringBuffer properties = new StringBuffer();
for ( String property : properties_to_pass ) {
    String value = System.getProperty(property);
    if ( value != null ) {
        String r = String.format("-D%s=%s ", property, value);
        properties.append( r );
    }
}
```

And after the above ...

```
String command_arg = properties.toString();
String command = String.format("java %s -jar Torpedo.jar", command_arg);
java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime.exec( command );
```

Very naive solution, but works anyway. But still not sure that there might be a better solution. Any further comments are welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Java 1.5+` it is highly recommended to use `ProcessBuilder` to create processes as it allows a lot of convenience methods to achieve what you are trying.

You can achieve sharing of System Properties with `ProcessBuilder` as following.

```
Properties props = System.getProperties();
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(new String[] {"java", "-jar","Xxx.jar"});
Map<String, String> env = builder.environment();
for(String prop:props.stringPropertyNames()) {
    env.put(prop, props.getProperty(prop));
}
Process process = builder.start();
```

With this code from your Child Process you can access any System Properties you pass using `-D` in your Parent Process using `System.getProperty` method.

Comment: Good answer. But this solution has a problem that the properties are  transferred to subprocesses as environment variables. Thus, the subprocesses are not correctly configured by the system properties. I checked it out by a sample program. Anyway, Thanks.

Comment: System properties and environment variables are different things.  While it's true the subprocess can read the properties out of the environment variable and set them, libraries (including the standard library) generally only check properties once, when they're first used, and store the result in a static field.  Thus it's important to pass them on the command line, not through environment variables.

Comment: How do you actually pass the processbuilder the -D properties?  I tried "-DpropName", "propValue" "class" but that did not work

Comment: when you invoke the Jar. java -DpropName=propValue -jar my.jar